# Writing a regular expression for my specific code

Tags: javascript, css, regex, replace

I've been trying to get help with this for a few days now, I've asked a dozen questions, all of which get marked duplicate (Which after thorough investigation of the linked questions, I find out it's a different issue) and a few unhelpful comments. This time, I'm coming at it from a different angle.
So far, I've got this working:

```
var themes = [
  'red',
  'pink',
  'purple',
  'deep-purple',
  'indigo',
  'blue',
  'light-blue',
  'cyan',
  'teal',
  'green',
  'lime',
  'khaki',
  'yellow',
  'amber',
  'orange',
  'deep-orange',
  'blue-grey',
  'brown',
  'grey',
  'dark-grey',
  'black'
]

themes.forEach((theme)=>{
  HTTP.get('https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3-theme-${theme}.css', (err, res)=>{
    console.log(`/*${theme}*/\n${res.content
      .replace(/w3-theme/g, theme)
      .replace(/w3-text-theme/g, `${theme}-text`)
      .replace(/w3-border-theme/g, `${theme}-border`)
      .replace(/w3-hover-theme/g, `${theme}-hover`)
      .replace(/w3-hover-text-theme/g, `${theme}-hover-text`)
      .replace(/w3-hover-border-theme/g, `${theme}-hover-border`)
      .replace(`${theme}-action`, `btn-${theme}`)
    }\n`)
  })
}
```

It's output is one of these for each color:

```
/*lime*/
.lime-l5 {color:#000 !important; background-color:#fcfdf3 !important}
.lime-l4 {color:#000 !important; background-color:#f5f8d7 !important}
.lime-l3 {color:#000 !important; background-color:#eaf1af !important}
.lime-l2 {color:#000 !important; background-color:#e0ea87 !important}
.lime-l1 {color:#000 !important; background-color:#d6e35f !important}
.lime-d1 {color:#000 !important; background-color:#c1d325 !important}
.lime-d2 {color:#fff !important; background-color:#acbb21 !important}
.lime-d3 {color:#fff !important; background-color:#96a41d !important}
.lime-d4 {color:#fff !important; background-color:#818c19 !important}
.lime-d5 {color:#fff !important; background-color:#6b7515 !important}

.lime-light {color:#000 !important; background-color:#fcfdf3 !important}

/*These lines need to be added via a replace statement*/
.btn-lime-light {color:#000 !important; background-color: #fcfdf3 !important}
.btn-lime-light:hover {color:#000 !important; background-color:#f5f8d7 !important; border-color:#f5f8d7 !important}
/*They aren't currently here*/

.lime-dark {color:#fff !important; background-color:#6b7515 !important}
.btn-lime {color:#fff !important; background-color:#6b7515 !important}

.lime {color:#000 !important; background-color:#cddc39 !important}
.lime-text {color:#cddc39 !important}
.lime-border {border-color:#cddc39 !important}

.lime-hover:hover {color:#000 !important; background-color:#cddc39 !important}
.lime-hover-text:hover {color:#cddc39 !important}
.lime-hover-border:hover {border-color:#cddc39 !important}
```

I have tried adding the following, in almost every variation I can fathom (I.E. Adding flags, changing notation, breaking it up, etc.):

```
.replace(/(\.(.*)-l4 .*#(.*?) .*#(.*) .*}(\n.*?)*-light.*?#(.*?) .*#(.*) .*})/, `$1\n.btn-$2-light {color:#$6 !important; background-color: #$7 !important}\n.btn-$2-light:hover {color:#$3 !important; background-color:#$4 !important; border-color:#$4 !important}`)
```

To no avail, it find 0 matches contrary to [My online tests](https://regex101.com/r/lC0eFT/4/).

My question is: How should I go about adding those 2 lines?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? See [ask] and [mcve] for details on how to ask a good question folks can answer

Comment: Perhaps the styles are being loaded after your Javascript runs

Comment: @HoriaComan I'm trying to add 2 lines to my css via a replace statement

Comment: @robertotomás My front-end is all reactive, and would refresh anyways, but, I'm also getting the correct console logs, so this isn't the issue

Comment: Please add more information about what you're trying to achieve here. From the current question, it appears you want to log two additional lines to the console. That seems pointless, so I think we're missing something in your explanation.

Comment: @JamieWeston I have edited the question to add some more relevant info. I'm keeping as a console log because I know how to finish it if I can get it to log correctly.

Comment: If some regex works in online trsterst and does not work in real code the tests were not performed correctly. Try replacing `.*` and `.*?` with `[\s\S]*?`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's still failing to match anything

Comment: Your question is still not clear. What 2 lines you would like to add?

Comment: The ones that are marked as "These lines need to be added"

Answer (score 0):

I have found a fix.

```
var ps = {
  'l4color':new RegExp(`\\.${theme}-l4 .*?#(.*?) `),
  'l4bg':new RegExp(`\\.${theme}-l4 .*?-color:#(.*?) `),
  'lightcolor':new RegExp(`\\.${theme}-light .*?#(.*?) `),
  'lightbg':new RegExp(`\\.${theme}-light .*?-color:#(.*?) `),
}
var as = {}
for(var p in ps){
  as[p] = ps[p].exec(rules)[1]
}
```

That allows me to instead of using a replace function, just make another log:

```
`.btn-${theme}-light {color:#${as.lightcolor} !important; background-color: #${as.lightbg} !important}\n.btn-${theme}-light:hover {color:#${as.l4color} !important; background-color:#${as.l4bg} !important; border-color:#${as.l4bg} !important}\n`
```

Of course, it doesn't allow things to line up all nice and neat, but it IS working.